# How much less to charge as a senior/new graduate for a identity+web package?

Tags: business, client-relations, freelance, identity

**First off, some context:** I am a second-semester senior in a graphic design program and will be graduated for most the the project described below. I have worked in an agency before as the main designer on a similar non-profit identity + web package, but this is the first time I will be doing it completely on my own. My portfolio has been seen by a several top-quality freelance print/branding designers in my area and they really liked my work.

The project is a branding package that will include a full identity, platform based website design, a brochure and print templates.

I have looked for similar posts here and established that:

1. Charging a fixed fee is best, based on time/value estimates: [Which is a better design pricing model?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/18142/which-is-a-better-design-pricing-model)
2. Quality should determine the pricing just as much experience: [Should I charge less for being a freelance entry level graphic designer?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/27775/should-i-charge-less-for-being-a-freelance-entry-level-graphic-designer)

I'm trying to determine how to price the identity package and it's pieces.

That said, I know that the non-profit is just now getting the funding to do this and don't seem to have a lot set aside on the budget - hence they are contacting an entry level guy. This is also primarily for someone I am related to (not always the best of ideas, but I'm willing to work with it.)

**For someone in my position, at what range of the spectrum what would you recommend charging?** Prices online for this kind package have a very wide range, from $800-$3k+. I'm honestly concerned they are not familiar with the cost of identity design & web design like this and will push for a lower price than I realistically deserve.

This is my first genuine rodeo in the freelance world and I would like to start off on the right foot.

EDIT:
Additional information that is noteworthy - I live in a area with below average design wages, but for a client across the country in a higher wage area, so I was shooting for national average in the US.

To perhaps clarify the question better, it would boil down to two questions:

A) **Even as a brand new freelance designer, is it standard to stick to market pricing?** And the continuing answer seems to be a "yes!"

B) **Is there a better rubric for entry-level pricing than what is floating around on the internet?** The GAG Handbook is out there, but doesn't seem to be easily translated to the needs of designers that are brand new to the field.

Comment: +1 for quality of post. You may however need to state where you are because it affects things quite heavily. I wouldnt charge any less because of the reasons you have stated. As you dont want to loose the gig later to another new designer. Dont trample prices.

Comment: I **really** don't know how *anyone* but you can determine *your* pricing.

Comment: There wont be an accurate answer to this question because we do not know all the factors that would be needed.  My advise to you is to check out the freelance SE site for further Q&As.

Comment: Note; "What do I charge" is pretty much off-topic at Freelance.SE. But they do have some existing questions regarding rates.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, despite the question perhaps having too many variables to be useful to the community at large.

I'll look into Freelance SE - I hadn't been aware of it previously and this kind of question could easily be formatted in a way that would fit better there.

Comment: Yes.  I've worked with 20-year experienced designers who couldn't design...mostly because they were not aware of how to use more current toolsets.  And I've worked with first year undergrads who can design better than I'll ever be able to.  No one can price your work but you is great advice.  And what you price it as is what you're worth.

Comment: I appreciate the advice. I'm currently in the midwest (Indiana) and the market here is rough. The above mentioned project fell through, but still struggling with issues related to it. I've been told I have a good portfolio, but places either don't have positions, are looking for people with 5+ full years experience on their resume, or are offering part time work barely paying above minimum wage  (I wish I was exaggerating on that last point, but it's true). Finding people who are willing to pay what other freelancers would charge for similar quality work is my current conundrum.